# WinForms ReportViewer HTML Interactivity Not Working

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am trying to render a report via a C# application.  The report successfully renders when I use both the "HTML5" and "HTML4.0" extensions, however the interactivity of the report is missing.  Specifically the expand/collapse feature of a Matrix cell.  Here is the code segment:

[image]

The Winform version is Assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91

Does anyone know what I am missing to keep enable the interativity of the report?

Comment: What is SetFlag(ReportOutputFlags.ReportOutputFlagsPDF) doing? Why do you want a PDF output if your'e trying to use interactive HTML? You won't be able to do the expand/collapse within a PDF?

Comment: That is just a flag used for some external exporting process to do with Google Protocol Buffers.  It is not part of the winforms reportviewer stuff, but I wanted to show the entire function.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.  I had the DeviceInfo-HTMLFragment element set to true.  Setting it to false, enabled the interactive features.

```
      "<DeviceInfo><HTMLFragment>False</HTMLFragment></DeviceInfo>";
```